# ACAccountStore swift2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

¿Cómo hago para crear una cuenta de mi aplicación con  `ACAccountStore` en `swift2` y `Xcode` ya que solo me muestra facebook y twitter pero no los voy a utilizar. Necesito crear es una cuenta que sea de mi aplicación. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no es posible crear cuentas que sean de tu aplicación.

Para poder crear una cuenta necesitas un ACAccountType, y según [la documentación (en inglés)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountTypeClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ACAccountType) esto no es posible:

> An `ACAccountType` object encapsulates information about all accounts of
>   a particular type. You do not create account type objects directly. To
>   obtain an account type, use the `accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:`
>   method or the `accountType` property of an account object.

Traducción libre:

> Un objeto de tipo `ACAccountType` encapsula información sobre todas las cuentas de un tipo en particular. No puedes crear objetos de este tipo directamente. Para obtener un tipo de cuenta, usa el método `accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:` o la propiedad `accountType` de un objeto `account`.